# jQuery slideDown slideUp error

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I am using the following code to animate a `slideDown`/`slideUp` effect when I hover over an element. The `slideDown` appears to be working fine, but when the mouse is no longer hovering over the element, the `slideUp` doesn't kick in.

```
$('div.guest-tile-holder').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('div.options-bar').slideDown('slow');
}), function() {
    $(this).find('div-options-bar').slideUp('slow');
};
```

What am I missing to get the `slideUp` to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a syntax error (close bracket on line 3 should be on line 5) and typo in the 2nd hover function.  You were doing a find for `'div-options-bar'`, not `'div.options-bar'`

```
$('div.guest-tile-holder').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('div.options-bar').slideDown('slow');
}, function() {
    $(this).find('div.options-bar').slideUp('slow');
});
```

Comment: There was definitely a syntax error, but that doesn't appear to have solved the problem. The same thing happens unfortunately.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Crap - how did I miss that? Thanks anyway.